# Type 'x[] | null' is not assignable to type 'x[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I'm having an issue binding a value in angular.
I have an observable returning an array as so:

```
entity$ = new Observable<Entity[]>(observer => {
if (this.entities[this.selectedEntityId] !== undefined) {
  observer.next([this.entities[this.selectedEntityId]]);
}
observer.complete();
})
.pipe(filter<Entity[]>(e => e !== undefined));
```

After that I'm trying to bind to it like this:

```
<dx-list>
   [selectedItems]="entityService.entity$ | async"
</dx-list>
```

Although I'm getting the error:

```
Type 'Entity[] | null' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
```

I'm relatively new to angular so I'm stumped on this issue.

Comment: Possibly it's because `async` pipe firstly emits `null` value, then - actual value. It's by design, but your dx-list component selectedItems @Input can't handle `null`. You must ensure that value is not-null. Directive *ngIf="entity$ | async as entity" may be useful.

Comment: As a side note, Observable constructor is rarely used. Functions `of` and `from` creates observable almost from anything. Also, `filter` operator here is redundant because your observable will never emit `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick fix would be `[selectedItems]="$any(entityService.entity$ | async)"`

Comment: This worked in achieving what I want, although it's quite possible I'm not following best practice. I've accepted this as it does answer the question.

Comment: True, it’s not a nice solution but a quick fix

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the `entityService.entity$` observable before passing it to the `selectedItems` by using `*ngIf`, which will narrow it to `Entity[]` type instead of `Entity[] | null`, like the following:

```html
<dx-list
  *ngIf="entityService.entity$ | async as entity"
  [selectedItems]="entity"
>
</dx-list>
```